# Как получить значение min и max в bootstrap slider?

Tags: bootstrap, slider

Есть горизонтальный slider с двумя ползунками. Рядом с со слайдером есть два input в котором рендерица минимальное и максимальное значение ползунков. Как мне во время собития перемещения ползунков и вовремя остановки сохранять (записывать) выбранные значения.

```
<input class="min" type="text" disabled value="0" />
<input class="max" type="text"  disabled value="10"/>
<input style="width:550px;" value="" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="10" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[1,10]" type="text" id="sl2" >

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var slider = $('#sl2');
      slider.slider({
          formatter: function(value) {
          var selector = $('#sl2'); 
          var mini = 0; //как получить min?
          var maxi = 10; //как получить max?
          $(".max").val( maxi );
          $(".min").val( mini );

         return value;
          }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Решено с бубном. На каждое событие слайдера, функция formatter вызывается три раза. И в каждом цикле в value разные форматы.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var slider = $('#sl2');
        var cnt = 1;
        slider.slider({
        formatter: function(value)
        {
            if ( cnt === 1 )
            {
                cnt = 2;
                return value;
            }
            if ( cnt === 2 )
            {
                cnt = 3;
                $(".min").val( value );
                return value;
            }
            cnt = 1;
            $(".max").val( value );
            return value;
          }
      });
    });/*end ready*/
```